# Why does Alert.show() give me two Alert boxes?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a strange behavior when I use `Alert.show` in a function that takes a `DataGridEvent`.

When the `Alert.show` is executed the function runs twice.

This is the code:

```
private function onItemEnd(event:DataGridEvent):void
{

    var pattern:RegExp =/[^a-z0-9A-ZéèçàêïôëËÉÊÈìíîïÌÍÎÏÇùúûü]/;
    var res:Boolean=pattern.test(texteSaisi);
    if(res==true){
        event.reason = DataGridEventReason.CANCELLED; 
        Alert.show("Le nom de l'option ne doit pas contenir des caractère spéciaux."); 
    }else{ 
        if (event.dataField == "libelle"){
            question.libelle = texteSaisi;
        }else if (event.dataField == "description") {
            question.description = texteSaisi;
        }
```

---

```
<mx:DataGrid 
    draggableColumns="false" 
    dataProvider = "{model.obtenirListeOptionsTarificationProposition}" 
    id = "gridOptions"
    rowCount = "10" 
    doubleClickEnabled = "true"
    itemClick = "onItemClick(event)" 
    change = "onChange(event)"
    width = "80%" 
    editable = "true"
    itemEditEnd = "onItemEnd(event)">
```

When this function is called I have two alerts on the screen I don't know why.

Comment: It may be because you are calling a function with the `click` event and calling another function for the `change` event.  My guess is that both are being executed.

Comment: thx but, when i execute the code without the Alert.show it run only ones so i think the problem is with the alert .

Comment: I gave an attempt at re-working your question to make it a little more clear.  Hopefully I didn't confuse matters.  Since we don't see the itemClick or the onChange event handlers, it's tough to say whether they are the issue.  With no alert, are you sure that the onItemEnd handler is only executed once?

Comment: thx , there is an itemClick handler and an onChange handler, and the onItemEnd handler is executed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspected that using an Alert in conjunction with the `itemEditEnd` event is problematic. Wrote a simple test case, which behaves differently (mine seems to go into an endless loop).

The problem is this:

1. The `itemEditEnd` event can be dispatched in numerous ways: keyboard interaction (tabbing or pressing enter while editing a cell), mouse interaction, etc.
2. I start editing a cell. Then I hit tab/enter or click in another cell. This generates the `itemEditEnd` event **and** moves the focus to a new editable cell.
3. In the event handler for the `itemEditEnd` event, an `Alert` is displayed. This pop up removes focus from that editable cell ... thus dispatching a second `itemEditEnd` event.

In my test app below, I have actually created an inifinite loop.

If you need to display an alert after the `itemEditEnd` event, maybe you can put some logic in the event handler (so it returns immediately the second time).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                grid.dataProvider=createCollection();
            }


            private function createCollection():ArrayCollection
            {
                var tmp:Array = [];
                for (var i:int = 1; i<11; i++)
                {
                    tmp.push({ data: Math.random()*100, label: i.toString() + " label" });
                }
                return new ArrayCollection(tmp);
            }

            private function onItemEditEnd():void
            {
                Alert.show("item edit end");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:DataGrid id="grid" itemEditEnd="onItemEditEnd()" editable="true" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: yes thats the explnation but now i have to find the logic to put a return the second time as u said . thank u for ur help :)

Comment: I fixed the problem by setting a boolean to true when the alert is fired the first time then i set it to false in the on click handler if the user try to change another item in onter row

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by setting a boolean to true when the alert is fired the first time then i set it to false in the on click handler if the user try to change another item in onter row.

Thx for the help ;)